# 2sxc - add new record to non 2sxc data table

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I know that this is more dnn than 2sxc question but I have some custom table inside dnn database and don't know how to do clasic dnn modules and using only 2sxc for module development.

My question is if you can give me some guides what is the easyest way for adding new record in this table from razor script or 2sxc apicontroller (preferred).

It would be the best if someone can paste some sample with code to get sql connection string, dnn database object qualifier and sql with command execution.
I don't need any relationship stuf.

From there I think that I can figured out how to make also edit and delete and post code back that others can see.

I don't plan to use this for many stuf but we have some sensors and aplication with a lotoff events and need custom table I can easy clear and index, and don't want that this data is EAV tabels.

For later I know how to get data back for visualization over sql datasource inside 2sxc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the far future we'll create a generic API to store to any kind of repository (EAV, SQL, CSV, Json, etc.) but for now, you'll just have to code it.

Basically your question isn't actually related to 2sxc - I recommend you simply google things like "save data to SQL using WebApi" or something - then put this code into an API controller in 2sxc.

At the moment I don't have any demo-code, but if you do create a demo, I would be glad to blog about it and publish in on https://2sxc.org/en/apps

Comment: I created small dnn module for creating data tables, and with use of petapoco create small api. Can you give me some guides how to make 2sxc module to create datatable or this is imposible?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your question is where could you put installation code. At the moment there is no standard feature, but the easiest way to do it is to create a default view (so it's shown at first, when a user uses the app the first time), where a button-click would call your code. The code can be in the view or in an API. It's not perfect, but gets the job done.